# Using separate stylesheet for partials

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a older rails system which is using an older version of bootstrap. I want to start moving things to bootstrap 4 and would like to start with the header and footer. The header and footer are being rendered as partials in the application view file.

**application.html.erb**

```
<head>
     <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all" %>
</head>
<body>
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>
</body
```

Lets just say the stylesheet link tag needs to be inside the application.html file there is other things in the application.html file that need it.

**Application.css**

```
 *= require bootstrap_and_overrides
 *= require cosmo/loader
 *= require cosmo/bootswatch
 *= require cosmo/font-awesome
```

I can't remove any of the required files because it will effect the rest of my pages.

I want to use the bootstrap cdn for my header and footer

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

How can I achieve using only the bootstrap cdn for the header and footer and exclude the required css files for these two partials?

Answer (score 0):

It is good that you're upgrading to the newer version of bootstrap but I would recommend you to not try to use separate bootstrap for different partials.

1. There will be no straight and clean to do so I believe so you'll be wasting your time and effort.
2. It will increase the loading time of your view
3. Alone Bootstrap CSS may not work for many components you'll also need latest jQuery/Javascript to make it work.

I'll suggest you to create a new branch (hopefully you'll be using Git) and take your time to upgrade Bootstrap in that and merge whenever you feel you're ready.

Comment: I'll definitely be taking my time and going through upgrading everything on a separate branch, but there is over 700 pages that I would have to go through, I just needed a quick upgrade to their nav bar for right now.